# Use 80211 bgn at 5 GHz

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a HP Pavilion notebook - 15-ab028tx with Realtek rtl8723be 802.11 bgn. I want to use 5 Ghz for better speed. Is there any option?

Comment: Your best option is to buy an external USB Wireless-N adapter that has a 5Ghz band. HP is well known for locking the BIOS so that only “authorized” WiFi cards will work on a laptop. So, unless you do significant research and find evidence there is a 5Ghz card that will work in that laptop, it’ll be a crap shoot. Stick with the USB adapter.

Answer (score 3):

If a Wi-Fi NIC is called "bgn" and not "abgn" or "a/b/g/n/ac", then it's almost certainly 2.4GHz-only, and can't do 5GHz.

Laptops that come with a 2.4GHz-only Wi-Fi NIC preinstalled usually come with 2.4GHz-only antennas pre-installed as well. And the antennas usually aren't designed to be replaceable. So upgrading to a dual-band Wi-Fi card probably won't work well, because the antennas you have probably don't perform well at 5GHz.

Get a USB Wi-Fi adapter. I recommend 2x2 802.11ac.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, Realtek RTL8723be WiFi chip is 2.4 GHz only.

And as @Appleoddity said in the comments, even the hardware modification of changing the WiFi module might not be possible, as the BIOS might only accept "authorized" WiFi module types.